# How to merge shape and line color titles into one and edit legend in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, label, legend

I am trying to make a ggplot graph with combined shape and color legends but also be able to edit the legend labels.
I have the following code used to make a graph:

```
Year.Avocet <- (1940:1980)
N.Avocet <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 6, 5,
              9, 10, 15, 14, 25, 33, 33, 50,
              50, 43, 55, 56, 60, 67, 61, 59,
              50, 53, 68, 64, 75, 76, 92, 89,
              97, 92, 100, 84, 84, 82, 95)


dlogistic <- function(alpha, rd, N0, t) {
  N <- c(N0, numeric(t))
  for (i in 1:t) {
    N[i + 1] <- N[i] + rd * N[i] * (1 - alpha * N[i])
  }
  return(N)
}

t <- 40
a <- 1/90
rd <- 0.235
N0 <- 1
Nts <- dlogistic(alpha = a, rd = rd, N0 = N0, t = t)


Avocet.graph1 <- data.frame(Year.Avocet, N.Avocet, Nts)

Avocet.graph1 <- pivot_longer(Avocet.graph1, cols = c(N.Avocet, Nts), names_to = "Value", 
                              values_to = "Counttype")

Avocet.graph1$Value = factor(Avocet.graph1$Value, levels=c("Nts","N.Avocet"))

ggplot(Avocet.graph1, aes(x = Year.Avocet, y = Counttype, color = Value, shape = Value)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  labs(color= 'Population\nParameter', shape = 'Population\nParameter')+
  xlab ("Year")+
  ylab("Population")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
```

This is good, except it does not have the correct legend labels. I can correct those with this:

```
ggplot(Avocet.graph1, aes(x = Year.Avocet, y = Counttype, color = Value, shape = Value)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  labs(color= 'Population\nParameter')+
  xlab ("Year")+
  ylab("Population")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)+
 scale_color_discrete(labels=c("Modeled", "Observed"))
```

But then I have separate graphs again. How do I combine legends types while still retaining the ability to alter the legend label text?